# `background-size:100% or cover` causes javascript to slow

Tags: javascript, css, firefox

In FF 17 :

```
body{
  background:  url('foo/images/flowers.jpg');
  background-size:  100%;
  background-attachment:  fixed;
}
```

causes the page to move slow, this means the animation and even the mouse pointer trailing across the screen.

Once I remove the background image all is fine.

To troubleshoot I removed the Base64 representation of the image and linked directly to the image as shown above.

I can continue to isolate in this manner, but I'm wondering if this is a known issue.

---

Isolating further it is this property causing the issue.

```
  background-size:  100%;
```

Comment: Try with `background-size:  cover;`.

Comment: Firefox does tend to have performance issues with 'complex' backgrounds (quotes added for sarcasm). They were optimizing this though, why are you not using the latest FF20?

Comment: @Niels - I don't have access to upgrade...can you provide more info. about what issues FF has?

Comment: does this issue persist if you give `body` an fixed pixel size with `height:nnpx;` ?

Comment: @pure_code.com not much more info to give, I've seen several cases the past months where Firefox became ridiculously slow upon having to render multiple generated backgrounds. I wouldn't be surprised if it had more issues related to that. [This page in particular](http://lea.verou.me/css3patterns/) was a drama, much improved now in FF20.

Comment: @codelio - no if I fix the width, height, there is no issue.  This seems to be a issue with `background-size:100% or cover` which has been fixed in new FF.  If someone wants to answer it.

Comment: You can always answer your own questions, but if you're giving out free rep, I won't complain ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a issue with `background-size:100% or cover` which has been fixed in new FF.